# Does Java pass-by-value for arrays?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a question regarding the concept of Java using pass-by-value. I do a lot of programming in C but I am very inexperienced with Java so I have been writing some code to learn a bit more about it. I have read many stack-overflow questions regarding whether there is ever any pass-by-reference, the answer seems to be that Java always uses pass-by-value (with the slight deviation being it passes references to objects by value).

With this in mind I’ve managed to properly confuse myself, I don’t understand how the following example can be an instance of pass-by-value. I would appreciate an explanation as to the internal Java workings that I don’t understand.

I have the following code:

```
byte[] myByteArray = {23, 45, 67};
myHashMap.put(myKey, new TestClass(100, myByteArray, myOtherByteArray));
Arrays.fill(myByteArray, (byte)0);
```

Where `myHashMap` is a `ConcurrentHashMap` and `TestClass` is defined:

```
public class TestClass
{
  public final int number;
  public final byte[] byte1;
  public final byte[] byte2;

  public TestClass(int a, byte[] b, byte[] c)
  {
    number = a;
    byte1 = b;
    byte2 = c;
  }
}
```

When I use the debugger to step through the code I can see that the `byte1` variable stored in `TestClass` (And subsequently in the `ConcurrentHashMap`) is altered by the `Arrays.fill` call, my question is ... why?

When instantiating a new `TestClass` am I not passing `myByteArray` by value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects are used by passing a reference which is itself passed by value unless cloned using a copy constructor or Cloneable's `clone()` in which case the value of a reference to a new object is passed. Arrays are objects as well, and as thus are referents in this way. If one is modified, all other references held to it will reflect these changes.

Comment: Hmm, no. In Java all objects are passed by _value_, this has been [discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) a number of times in SO

Comment: I see, I was not aware that arrays were treated as objects. Thanks

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Technically it's the primitve reference to an object on the heap

Comment: @ÓscarLópez To be precise, objects are not passed at all; *references* are passed, and they are passed by value.

Comment: This is wrong and should be deleted. "Objects" are not values in Java and are not "passed". All values, regardless of type, are passed by value in Java. Period.

Comment: @newacct: It's not wrong.  The problem is in your narrow definition of "pass".  References are passed by value.  But the act of passing a reference is, in fact, passing the referent by reference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: No. Maybe you have a screwed up concept of "pass". You think things which are not values can be "passed"? "Pass by value" and "pass by reference" have very precise definitions, and relate to the semantics of the variable that you put into the function call syntax. It has nothing to do with "referents".

Comment: @newacct Am I going to confuse the OP here? The correct explanation, marked with the words "well, technically" is obviously there in the post. Edited, anyway.

Comment: @hexafraction: "All objects are passed by value to a reference" doesn't even make sense. What does that mean? Objects are not passed by value. Objects are not passed, period. This is even more confusing.

Comment: @newacct There, clarified again. *sighs at own poor wording*

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass by value.

Always.

The only tricky part is passing arguments to methods, which is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) stack overflow question.

(copy of important answer below)

---

Java is always pass-by-value. The difficult thing can be to understand that Java passes objects as references and those references are passed by value.

It goes like this:

```
public void foo(Dog d) {
  d.getName().equals("Max"); // true
  d = new Dog("Fifi");
  d.getName().equals("Fifi"); // true
}

Dog aDog = new Dog("Max");
foo(aDog);
aDog.getName().equals("Max"); // true In this example aDog.getName() will still return "Max". d is not overwritten in the function as the object reference is passed by value.
```

Likewise:

```
public void foo(Dog d) {
  d.getName().equals("Max"); // true
  d.setName("Fifi");
}


Dog aDog = new Dog("Max");
foo(aDog);
aDog.getName().equals("Fifi"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is because the premise of your question is flawed -- "arrays" cannot be passed. Arrays are objects, and objects are not values in Java. The only types in Java are primitive types and reference types (note: no "object types"), so the only values in Java are primitives and references.

> When I use the debugger to step through the code I can see that the
>   byte1 variable stored in TestClass (And subsequently in the
>   ConcurrentHashMap) is altered by the Arrays.fill call, my question is
>   ... why?

Your `byte1` variable has *not* been altered. `byte1` has a reference type; i.e. it is a reference. Its value is a memory address. This value remains the same.

The array object *that is pointed to* by `byte1` has had its contents changed.

> When instantiating a new TestClass am I not passing myByteArray by value?

Yes, you are.